# what happens if we give "777" permissions to /etc/sudoers?

Tags: linux, security, permissions, redhat-enterprise-linux

What happens if I give "777" permission to `/etc/sudoers`? I am looking at the security perspective. I want to know the importance of `/etc/sudoers` file as well.

Answer (score 5):

Anyone on your system, including anyone who can exploit any server on your system, can promote any user to root. This is basically removing security.

Comment: However, `sudo` will refuse to run at all if the `sudoers` file is writable by anyone but root.